# CARLA - Create Custom semantic tags Does not work

Tags: unreal-engine4, semantic-segmentation, carla

i followed the instructions on [Create semantic tags](https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tuto_D_create_semantic_tags/) to create my custom tags.

1. I created two new folders, ChevronSign and YellowLine
2. Then i added the tags to **`ObjectLabel.h`** in `LibCarla/source/carla/rpc`
3. Then i edited **`Tagger.cpp`** in `Unreal/CarlaUE4/Plugins/Carla/Source/Carla/Game`
4. And finally defined a color code in **`CityScapesPalette.h`** in `LibCarla/source/carla/image`.

I moved the assets in the according directory, and they appear black, so no label. Moving the assets in one of the default folders works just fine, the semantic tag gets displayed correct.

What i tried:

1. I changed the color of a default label and checked if the color would change. It did not.
2. I tried to rebuild carla with `make CarlaUE4Editor`, and an error because of the new tags:

```
/carla/Unreal/CarlaUE4/Plugins/Carla/Source/Carla/Game/Tagger.cpp:48:67: error: no member named 'ChevronSign' in 'carla::rpc::CityObjectLabel'
  else if (String == "ChevronSign")  return crp::CityObjectLabel::ChevronSign;

/carla/Unreal/CarlaUE4/Plugins/Carla/Source/Carla/Game/Tagger.cpp:49:67: error: no member named 'YellowLine' in 'carla::rpc::CityObjectLabel'
  else if (String == "YellowLine")   return crp::CityObjectLabel::YellowLine;
```

3. So i checked if there are other `ObjectLabel.h` files in my system and customized all of them as the first one. I found 3 of them.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI4u6.png)

Then the i ran `make CarlaUE4Editor` sucessfully. But the Semantic Tags still don't work.

Does anyone know which mistake i made? Is there a mistake in the [documentation](https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tuto_D_create_semantic_tags/)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. I just had to upgrade from carla 0.9.9 to 0.9.10.